# Baffling behavior when parsing ordinals with Moment JS. Bug?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm simply trying to go from a `moment` to a `string` and then back to a `moment`.

But it's not really working:

```javascript
f = 'dddd MMMM Do, YYYY'
s = 'Friday May 3rd, 2013'


d = moment().format(f)            # Sunday April 21st, 2013 
moment(d, f).format(f)            # Monday April 1st, 2013

moment(s, f)                      # Friday May 3rd, 2013
    .format(f)                    # Wednesday May 1st, 2013
```

It always parses the ordinal as the first day of the month.

Is there something wrong with my formatting? Or how I'm expecting `format()` to work?

Comment: From the documentation, it seems that the parser doesn't understand the "Do" token.

Comment: ... and that seems pretty lame :-)

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's not supported. I just thought all formats would be.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was raised a while back [here](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/637).

The solution is to ignore the letter portion of the ordinal dates when parsing, using `DD` instead of `Do`.

```
var f1 = 'dddd MMMM Do, YYYY';
var f2 = 'dddd MMMM DD, YYYY';

var a = moment().format(f1);
console.log(a);                    // Thursday June 20th, 2013

var b = moment(a, f1).format(f1);
console.log(b);                    // Saturday June 1st, 2013

var c = moment(a, f2).format(f1);
console.log(c);                    // Thursday June 20th, 2013
```

As you can see, the result of `b` is the first of the month, because it didn't understand what to do with the day number.  But `c` picked up the `20`, and ignored the extra `th` characters - yielding the correct result.