# Issue with Javascript Date format

Tags: javascript, parsing, date, momentjs

I am using Momentjs to validate a date/time string in Javascript .

```
var day= "Sunday, February 14th 2010, 3:25:50 pm";
var valid=moment(day,"dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a").isValid();
alert(valid);
```

This always returns false . I am not sure what the issue is .

I am using the Momentjs library - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/

I have created a jsfiddle as well - http://jsfiddle.net/FUDf7/1/

Please help .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Baffling behavior when parsing ordinals with Moment JS. Bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135430/baffling-behavior-when-parsing-ordinals-with-moment-js-bug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `D[th]` instead: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/FUDf7/2/)

ps I have no idea why `Do` not working

Answer (score 1):

I think 14th is your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/FUDf7/3/

```
var day= "Sunday, February 14 2010, 3:25:50 pm";
var valid=moment(day,"dddd MMMM D YYYY h:mm:ss a").isValid();
alert(valid);
```

Comment: But according to http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ , 14th should be a valid format matching with 'Do'

Comment: Haven't used it before so I don't know how it works. Try to make a separate example to make this 'Do' work.

Comment: @vladkras Yes, I guess he does. I don't know how moment.js parses strings to I cannot suggest something else right now. Your solution seems better.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no support for ordinals in parsing—see [the source code](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/blob/1ccf6b9e98161c4e1a603ac28712c9d0aeb77e46/moment.js#L638):

```
    /************************************
        Parsing
    ************************************/


    // get the regex to find the next token
    function getParseRegexForToken(token, config) {
        switch (token) {
        case 'DDDD':
            return parseTokenThreeDigits;
        case 'YYYY':
            return parseTokenFourDigits;
        case 'YYYYY':
            return parseTokenSixDigits;
        case 'S':
        case 'SS':
        case 'SSS':
        case 'DDD':
            return parseTokenOneToThreeDigits;
        case 'MMM':
        case 'MMMM':
        case 'dd':
        case 'ddd':
        case 'dddd':
            return parseTokenWord;
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            return getLangDefinition(config._l)._meridiemParse;
        case 'X':
            return parseTokenTimestampMs;
        case 'Z':
        case 'ZZ':
            return parseTokenTimezone;
        case 'T':
            return parseTokenT;
        case 'MM':
        case 'DD':
        case 'YY':
        case 'HH':
        case 'hh':
        case 'mm':
        case 'ss':
        case 'M':
        case 'D':
        case 'd':
        case 'H':
        case 'h':
        case 'm':
        case 's':
            return parseTokenOneOrTwoDigits;
        default :
            return new RegExp(token.replace('\\', ''));
        }
    }
```

It’s [been reported as a bug](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/247), but it’s [not going to get fixed](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/259) “unless there is more demand for this.”